# Change update restart prompt time in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-update

When downloading updates for Windows XP, it occasionally requires a reboot. Initially it prompts and allows you to say "ask me again later". On my computer at home, it asks me again about every 5 minutes. However, with my computer at work (both Windows XP Pro, SP3), it is more like every 3 hours that it prompts me. This leads me to believe there is a setting somewhere that configures this, but I don't know where it is. Can anyone confirm there is a setting for this and where it might be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Our very own Jeff Atwood ranted about this a few years ago:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000294.html

You should be able to at least turn it off.

> There are two settings and both will
>   work, so it's your choice. Either
>   enable No auto-restart for schedule
>   Automatic Updates installations or set
>   Re-prompt for restart with scheduled
>   installations to a long time interval,
>   like 1440 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

The synopsis goes like this:

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and run `gpedit.msc`, you should get a window like this:

[image: gpedit.msc]

In case that's not legible it's:

1. Do not display 'Install Updates and Shut Down' in Shut Down Windows dialog box

   - Do not adjust default option to 'Install Updates and Shut Down' in Shut Down Windows dialog box
   - Configure Automatic Updates
   - Specify intranet Microsoft update service location
   - Enable client-side targeting
   - Reschedule Automatic Updates scheduled installations
   - No auto-restart for scheduled Automatic Updates
   - Automatic Updates detection frequency
   - Allow Automatic Updates immediate installation
   - Delay Restart for scheduled installations
   - Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations.

Personally I chose to enable 7, 9 and 11. Enabling 7 actually disables the auto-restart. 11 was enabled and set to it's max value (1440) with the scroll wheel. I took this from my own [question](https://superuser.com/questions/15165/windows-7-is-shutting-down-unexpectedly-according-to-the-logs) which was about Windows 7.

### Addendum

It's been pointed out that Home editions of Windows don't come with `gpedit.msc`, and you must therefore [set things directly](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/prevent-windows-update-from-forcibly-rebooting-your-computer/) in the registry. There's probably more settings you could add besides `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` ... In fact I'm going to check that now. Okay in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU` add:

1. `AutoInstallMinorUpdates` = 1

   - `NoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers` = 1
   - `RebootRelaunchTimeout` = 1440 (decimal)
   - `RebootRelaunchTimeoutEnabled` = 1 [I'm actually curious if that's what I wanted]
2. `RebootWarningTimeout` = 30 (decimal)

   - `RebootWarningTimeoutEnabled` = 1 [I think the above four don't happen due to #2]

Keys #5 and #6 are for enabling #10 from the above set and setting it to its maximum.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can change it, it's a setting in the group policy editor.

Look under Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Windows Update. there's a setting called "Re-prompt for restart with scheduled installations". Just set this to the time your want (Or turn it off)