# Stop the reminder that I have to reboot the computer after installing Windows updates

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change update restart prompt time in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/7093/change-update-restart-prompt-time-in-windows-xp)

How can I stop the reminder that I have to reboot the computer after installing Windows updates in Windows XP Professional SP3? I close it the first time, but it keeps coming back.

Thanks.

Comment: I never found a way--this is one of the many reasons I stopped using Windows. Ubuntu installs updates and waits like a polite English butler for you to okay the reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here: [Change update restart prompt time in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/7093/change-update-restart-prompt-time-in-windows-xp)